# Close application properly

Tags: vb.net

I would like to close my application properly after it lose connection to database.

The database check is implemented within Task which is running behind. When connection is lost users can have of course many open forms in application.

When connection is lost I got event which is raised and method handler on main form and there I would like to be able to close everything. Currently to be sure to not raise error (cause task) I did it inside Invoke, one message information to user and second to close application itself.

It works I tested it. However meantime when application is closing `Application.Exit()` I see some errors messages showing very fast behind and application (not able to read them very quick) is closed immediately. My question is this approach correct?

```
Public Sub MyEventHandler
  Invoke(Sub()
        MsgBox("No connection to server, application will be closed")

                       Application.Exit()
                   End Sub)
   End Sub
```

Comment: Check that you close all Readers and Streams you have opened

Comment: Application.Exit() is too friendly.  Entirely too much code runs and it can trivially be stopped by the app with e.Cancel = True.  Use Environment.Exit() instead.  Or better yet, just don't catch nasty problems that you can't handle.  Your app should fail gracefully on an unhandled exception with a decent diagnostic for the user.  Very, very important.  Writing an event handler for the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException event is never really optional.

Comment: @Hans Passant Envinorment.Exit will just terminate the process when application.exit will try to close all forms before shut down, isn't better?

Comment: @Mederic I use using connection in all of my queries so they should be disposed correctly even if i do Exit app am i right?

Comment: @Arie depends on the code try using the `Using` for everything that has `IDisposable`